# python resolve data frame value to a variable value

Tags: python, dataframe

I am learning python and I have a issue resolving data frame value to a variable value within.

I have variable:

```
nss_id=uv3bb
```

I have a data frame value `Df[‘app_id’].values[0]` , which gets me the value `nss`

`Print(Df[‘app_id’].values[0]+”_id”)` which gives the values `nss_id`, I want that to be resolved to `uv3bb`. Can somebody tell me the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

one approach would be to use the eval function...
if you have a variable defined as:

```
nss_id = 'uv3bb'
```

and your df output gives you:

```
Df[‘app_id’].values[0]+”_id”
'nss_id'
```

you can do this...
say:

```
x = Df[‘app_id’].values[0]+”_id”
x
'nss_id'
```

then:

```
eval(x)
'uv3bb'
```

another approach would be to make a dict with var names and values

Comment: Thanks Derek this is helpful I’ll try that